# What is the simplest way to add defining lines to a stacked area chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently have a stacked area chart with individual security weights that sum to 1.00. My current task is to add defining lines to the chart so to further distinguish the colors.

```
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize = (7, 3.5), dpi = 200)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
df.plot(ax = ax, kind="area", legend = True, color = hex_list)
```

What would be the simplest (or most effective way) of add white lines between each new series?

Comment: Can you add a small sample df?

Comment: And do you have an example of how you want your output to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[.2,.3,.4,.5],'B':[.1,.2,.1,.2],'C':[.7,.5,.5,.3]})
ax = df.plot.area(stacked=True)
df.plot(stacked=True, ax=ax, legend=False, color='white')
```

Output:

[image]